# Need batch-file to move 1 random file

Tags: file, random, batch-file, move

I'm looking for a batch script that can move 1 random image file from one folder to another, so I'm thinking it would be a wildcard for name and extension since the images could be different file types, I've tried different scripts I've found on here already but had no success with those. I can supply the exact directory locations if that would make it easier:
source directory: `C:\Users\Chris\DSFS`
destination directory: `C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\DSFS`

It's for a humor site and I'm trying to get it automated, as it is now anything in the dropbox location goes to the cloud and put to the site, with a working script I can have the script automated with windows to send the images over three times a day and just fill the folder, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "source=C:\Users\Chris\DSFS\*"
for %%a in ("%source%\*") do set /a files+=1
set /a skip=%random%%%files
if %skip% EQU 0 (SET "skip=") ELSE SET "skip=skip=%skip%"
for /f "%skip% delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%"') do (
    IF DEFINED files (
        ECHO MOVE "%%~fa" "C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\DSFS"
        SET "files="
    )
)
```

Comment: Endoro, I added a `goto :done` command at the end so it only copies one file.  You'd typo'd the /f so I edited it.

Comment: One issue is that it can return an empty string. I added a loop which should fix that.

Comment: thanks for the quick help, I have it all set up in a bat file and images in the folder but when run the cmd window says "the system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @foxidrive thank you for your help :). I made more changes to enable "`skip=0`".

Comment: just replaced the old code with the new code, when run it gives this as an error: Divide by zero error. 0 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: would it be easier to have it move like the first file in the folder instead of a random file in the folder? at the core it really just needs to move only one file from source to destination

Comment: @user2673119 divide by zero? But there is no division in the code... I tested it here, works fine. Please post the output of `dir C:\Users\Chris\DSFS\*` eg. at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: I found a script that works perfectly, thanks to everyone who helped on this one